# What method to use to connect and embedded android device to a WiFi network

Tags: remote-access, wifi-direct

**Situation:**

- We build devices with embedded android tablets that run on android 12 (Snow Cone).
- The screen is not easily accessible

**What we try to achieve:**

- We would like to connect the embedded device to the local WiFi through a companion app. To be more precise: We would like to use another device to link the embedded android tablet to the local WiFi, without having to click a prompt on the embedded tablet.

**What the current problem is:**

The API call that allowed to change Wi-Fi settings through an app without a confirmation has been removed in Android 10, and new versions of the OS are not backwards-compatible with the old API calls. New API call that replaced it requires accepting the change by tapping a notification displayed on the tablet.

Is there a way to circumvent this?

Thank you in advance!